# How to prevent click event from firing when turning it back "on" with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I've got a table of message subjects and I've made each tr clickable to navigate to the message details page. However there is also a trash icon that the user can click on to mark the message for deletion via $.ajax, this is done by first turning the tr event handler "off". The problem is that when turning the tr click event handler back on the click is processed and the user is navigated to the details page.

I attempted to add e.stopPropogation(); immediately after the $.ajax call and before the "on"  setting of the tr but that prevents the event from being turned on. Adding it after does not prevent the desired behavior.

So my question is, how do I turn the click event back "on" for the tr after having turned it off, but not fire the event off in the process.

Code:

```
$("#messageTable tbody tr").on("click", function () {
        var id = $(this).find('td:first').find('input').val();
        window.location.replace('/Messages/Read/'+id);
    });

    $('.icon-trash').on("click", function (e) {

        // turn off tr click to prevent navigation
        $("#messageTable tbody tr").off("click");

        // grab the message Id from the hidden input
        var messageId = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
        var tr = $(this).parent().parent();

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "MarkMessageForDeletion"
            , type: "GET"
            , data: { id: messageId }
            , dataType: "json"
            , async: true
            , success: function (data) {
                if (data === "1") {
                    tr.remove();
                }
            }
        });

        // turn click back on 
        $("#messageTable tbody tr").on("click", function () {
            var id = $(this).find('td:first').find('input').val();
            window.location.replace('/Messages/Read/' + id);
        });           
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried adding 'return false;' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the trash icon is a descendant of the `tr`, there's no need to turn off the event handler on the row. Simply call [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) (note the spelling, perhaps that's why it wasn't working for you?) from your trash icon click handler.

```
$("#messageTable tbody tr").on("click", function () {
    var id = $(this).find('td:first').find('input').val();
    window.location.replace('/Messages/Read/'+id);
});

$('.icon-trash').on("click", function (e) {

    // prevent the click reaching the row
    e.stopPropagation();

    // grab the message Id from the hidden input
    var messageId = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "MarkMessageForDeletion"
        , type: "GET"
        , data: { id: messageId }
        , dataType: "json"
        , async: true
        , success: function (data) {
            if (data === "1") {
                tr.remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Gratuitous live example](http://jsbin.com/evitef)

---

For what it's worth, you can make the code a bit more robust by using `var tr = $(this).closest('tr');` rather than `.parent().parent()`. [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) finds the closest matching ancestor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the tip on closest.

Comment: @user1194094: No worries, glad that helped. Another thing you may find handy is event delegation. [Here's my gratuitous example using event delegation](http://jsbin.com/evitef/2). Note how I can add a row and not have to do anything to hook up the handlers, because they're really hooked up on the `tbody`, not individual `tr` or `.icon-trash` elements. Best,

Comment: Talk about going above and beyond, thanks for the sample, it will help as I get my code from "functional" to "optimal".

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the `.icon-trash` elements inside the `#messageTable tbody tr`s, and what you might want to do is to stop them from bubbling and forget about the `off("click")` call:

```
$("#messageTable tbody tr").on("click", function () {
    var id = $(this).find('td:first').find('input').val();
    window.location.replace('/Messages/Read/'+id);
});

$('.icon-trash').on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 

    // grab the message Id from the hidden input
    var messageId = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "MarkMessageForDeletion"
        , type: "GET"
        , data: { id: messageId }
        , dataType: "json"
        , async: true
        , success: function (data) {
            if (data === "1") {
                tr.remove();
            }
        }
    });

    // I also like to return false from the handler,
    // which is an old-school way of e.stopPropagation()
    return false;
});
```

What was happening is that the click was handled on the button, bubbled up and it was handled on the `tr` element as well. The `e.stopPropagation();` and the `return false;` statements stop that from happening, it won't bubble up. The `off` and `on` calls didn't change this behaviors, because they didn't actually stop the bubbling (the bubbling starts after the return of this function).

Comment: `return false` does more than just `stopPropagation` (it also does `preventDefault`). Probably doesn't matter in this case. But if you've called `stopPropagation`, there's no point in returning false unless you also want to prevent the default.

Comment: It's an old habit I have from a long time ago, but thanks for making that clear, I forgot about that.